# How does Emacs decide whether a frame's background-mode is light or dark, and how can I affect the decision?

Tags: faces, frame-parameters

I am finding that in some cases (e.g. when `TERM=xterm-16color`), the expression

```
(frame-parameter nil 'background-mode)
```

...evaluates to `light` when it is in fact a dark background.

How does Emacs decide the value of a frame's `background-mode` at startup, and how can I affect the decision?

**EDIT:** I realize that I can always run `(setq frame-background-mode 'whatever)`, but this is not what I mean by "affect the decision" above.  Rather, I mean: how can I modify the way I invoke Emacs (including the shell environment in which I invoke it) so that its default algorithm for setting `frame-background-mode` at startup *gets it right*.

**EDIT2:** I do not see how the answers to [Emacs Blue color too dark](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/emacs-blue-color-too-dark) answer my post's main question, namely: how does Emacs figure out the value it should set `frame-background-mode` to at startup?  (For the sake of this question, assume that there is no `.emacs`/initialization file at startup.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emacs Blue color too dark](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/emacs-blue-color-too-dark)

Comment: @NickD: thank you for the pointer, but I don't see the answer to my first question (i.e., how does Emacs set the value of `background-mode` to begin with) in that thread.  Also, though that thread does give at least one way to affect the decision (namely, by running `(setq background-mode ...)`) this is heavier than what I was hoping to find.  (My question's original version did not make this last point clear at all, but I just edited it to fix this.)

Comment: I meant to point to @wasamasa's answer in that question, not to the question itself but I messed it up. The links should be https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36032/14825. And as it turns out, he has also written an answer to your other question (TLDR: it is not pretty and it does not really work): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16811/14825 and check out the blog post that he links to. AFAIK, nothing has changed in that area in the past 6 years.

Comment: @NickD: thank you for the clarification.  I still find phils' post below is the one that best answers the question I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code for `frame-set-background-mode` and `frame-terminal-default-bg-mode`.

The latter "checks the ‘frame-background-mode’ variable, the X resource
named "backgroundMode" (if FRAME is an X frame), and finally
the ‘background-mode’ terminal parameter."

Customize the `frame-background-mode` user option to enforce a value.

Individual terminals/emulators are handled via the various files in the `lisp/term/` directory; e.g.: `/usr/local/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/term/` (but depending on how Emacs is installed); or else refer to https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term

See the `README` file in that directory for details of how Emacs selects which of those files to load.  Once you've established which file is in use, you would need to read the code to see how backgrounds are established, as functionality can vary between terminals.